# JSF-2 updating form components from bean while calculating.

Tags: forms, jsf-2

I have method which performs a lot of calculations and I want to provide some feedback to the form from time to time when some conditions are met. That is , I want to update components on the form while the bean method is busy. At first I thought that it should be easy, but soon I realized, that these actions would violate JSF life cycle. Maybe there is a work around or something that could be done?

Answer (score -1):

You can for example refresh components from backing bean like this:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPartialViewContext().getRenderIds().add("componentsId");
```

And there are other solutions when you can i.e. load values from beans or servlets using using ajax push/pull.
Your requirements seems similar to some kind of progress bar which is also implemented in many frameworks like PrimeFaces etc.

Comment: The effect won't be visible until the request thread is finished running.